# How to use a CTE in a left outer join?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join a common table expression to an existing table (table1) as follows.

```
select column1, column2 from table1

left outer join

  ;with cte as (
    select column1, column2 from table2)

  select column1, column2 from cte

on table1.column1 = cte.column1
```

The errors are:

1. Incorrect syntax near ';'.
2. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a CTE for this task?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The CTE must come at the beginning of the query.

```
with cte as (
    select column1, column2 from table2
)
select column1, column2 from table1
   LEFT JOIN cte
on table1.column1 = cte.column1;
```

Comment: good answer, but I believe your parenthesis pairs are not correct